# Windows server firewall - to block all traffic except my IP

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall

I tried to block all the traffic and allow only my IP in windows firewall. Unfortunately its blocking all my traffic. Is there any priority level need to set in firewall ?. I don't have much knowledge in Windows as i'm a Linux Admin.

in Linux, first rule is preferred in  policy. In windows, I did the same put my allow rule first and put my Deny rule underneath.

Someone have any idea on what is the reason for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the built-in Windows firewall, deny rules take precedence over allow rules regardless of order.

If you're wanting to block all traffic, then you want to change the "default action" to "block"

**WARNING**: If you are connected remotely, this change may disconnect you from the computer.

First, add in your desired "Allow" rules and delete (or disable) your "Block" rules.

Open the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" snapin, select "Windows Firewall Properties", and then change the "Inbound Connections" and/or "Outbound Connections" to "Block"